# Sony Audio Control API with USB

Tags: sony-audio-control-api

I m using the Sony audio control API with a ZR5 and an USB key.
I can select the USB storage with the Json

```
{
 "method":"setPlayContent",
 "id":1,
 "params":[
  {
   "output":"extOutput:zone?zone=1",
   "uri":"storage:usb1"
  }
 ],
 "version":"1.2"
}
```

But impossible to start the playing. I can start it with my phone, but impossible to make pause or stop with the API.

The ZR5 don't support setPlayNextContent or pausePlayingContent .

How I can start the playing on an USB key, if it's possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support for playing from the USB is and very limited in the Audio Control API and is a remaining functionality from earlier versions. The best way to play from USB is to use the DLNA protocol.

You can find some examples at https://github.com/sonydevworld/audio_control_api_examples/blob/master/DLNA/ContentDirectory/browse.adoc and https://github.com/sonydevworld/audio_control_api_examples/blob/master/DLNA/AVTransport/play_file.adoc

Comment: Yeah ^^. Thx a lot, I haven't see this tutorial yet, I have a working code entirely in python made with it.